# Blank or empty number text box instead of zero value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have number text box as shown below.

```
<input type="number" ng-model="item.TotalUnitsCompleted" />
```

`TotalUnitsCompleted` model is an `int` field.So could you tell me how to set a blank or empty value instead of `0` on the above text box ? At this moment it shows as `0`.  Thanks in advance.

Note : I don't like to change the `int` model to `string`.

Comment: can you update in controller itself? item.TotalUnitsCompleted == 0?"":item.TotalUnitsCompleted;

Comment: @ssilas777 I can do that.But here I'm using above text box inside the `ngtable`.Then I have to execute extra loop for achieving that.Can I have any other solution ? Such as ng property on text box etc...where without writing extra loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to set `item.TotalUnitsCompleted = undefined;`

If you are using `ngTable`, just `ng-init` on each loop `ng-init="item.TotalUnitsCompleted = undefined"`

Here is an Example:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="TotalUnitsCompleted"  ng-init="TotalUnitsCompleted = initTotalUnits(TotalUnitsCompleted)"/>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.TotalUnitsCompleted = 5;

  $scope.initTotalUnits = function(units) {
    return (typeof units !== 'undefined' && units > 0 && units !== null) ? units : undefined;
  }
});
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IefZI7?p=preview)

Comment: But then it shows all fields as an empty.I need to show the other fields values instead of empty.Such as if it's having 2 then I need to show it. I have used `ng-init` method as you mentioned above.

Comment: @Sampath can you please update pluner example with your code?

Comment: You'r plunker is wrong even though it's working? But your code snippet above is working fine.Thanks a lot.I would like to ask one question though.Do you think which method is fast ? Above on or for-loop ?

Comment: For loop will be faster.. And here is the correct plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/IefZI7?p=preview

Comment: But with `ng-table` your method is very fast hence it's validating according to the pagination.GREAT.Thanks a lot :)